I am the person who uses the mouse with "their" right hand?
Well, I just read a sentence on reddit and it simply destroys my brain:

as a left handed person who uses the mouse with their right hand, i have always wanted to try a southpaw board and just never have but i might now.

Why not say "with my right hand"? Isn't it implicitly saying:

I, as a left handed person, who use the mouse with my right hand, [...].

Anyway, am I wrong and the sentence is no problem and formal?

The poster could equally well have used my. Evidently they were using the phrase to mean 'people who do that' as a group, of which 'I' happen to be one.

@KateBunting Thanks for your kind explanation.

Counterexample: “I am a person who uses the mouse with my left hand.  And so's my brother.”  “What?  He uses the mouse with your left hand, too??”

"as a left handed person who uses the mouse with their right hand" stands alone as a phrase. You don't know that it refers to the speaker until the word "I" comes along. The sentence could just as well have continued "..., you may want to try ...". If you replace "their" with "my" the overall meaning is the same but it becomes clear sooner that you are talking about yourself. In speech this distinction would be become more significant, stylistically at least. I find the original sentence perfectly natural and wouldn't have even questioned the use of "their".

This makes sense to me, the context matters. English is fun!

The Reddit sentence and your rewrite are both correct. The basic point is that the pronoun matches the noun that it refers to, and in the two choices the noun has changed.

As a left handed person who uses the mouse with their right hand, I have always wanted to try a southpaw board ...

In this example, their refers back to left handed people in general, not me in particular. The sentence in effect is saying, "As a member of a larger group consisting of left handed people who use the mouse with their right hand, I have always wanted..."

I, as a left handed person who use the mouse with my right hand, [...].

Here the subject is explicitly I from the beginning, and so my is the correct matching pronoun. Note that in this sentence person is implicitly referring back to me alone, not a larger group.

And my wife happens to be a left handed person, but even she doesn’t use the mouse with my right hand.

Shouldn't it be "I, as a left handed person, who uses the mouse with my right hand" or "I, as a left handed person, use the mouse with my right hand". Only just spotted that.

@timchessish If a relative clause is restrictive, it should not be set off with commas. Here, there are left handed people who use the mouse with their right hand (because most mouses are right handed) and left handed people who use the mouse with their left hand (because mouses are supposed to be used with your dominant hand, which is why most of them are right handed), so the relative clause is restrictive and thus should not be set off with commas

I think "their" refers not to left handed people in general, but to the specific left handed person who is the object of the prepositional phrase "as a ...".

@DavidZ: It's neither! It's referring to the subset of left handed people who also happen to use a mouse with their right hand.

@Kevin Hmm, well I'm not a professional language expert but that's not how I read it. Though I do still find that more plausible than that it refers to all left handed people. (I guess in a sense there are two separate questions: (1) does "their" refer to one person or a group, and (2) is the intent to include or exclude a person or people who use the mouse with the left hand. I wonder if we'd agree on the answers to either of those? The way I read the phrase, the answers are (1) one person (2) exclude; the answer seems to be saying (1) multiple people (2) include.)

@DavidZ: I read it as follows: "As a [general category of person], I [specific action]." The first clause is about the category, and only the second clause is about the specific individual.

@Kevin Oh perhaps we're talking about different phrases? I was referring to the one quoted in the answer, "As a ... who ...", not "As a ..., I ...". The two are different constructions and I think the analysis of their interpretations would be meaningfully different. (FWIW I would be happy to continue this discussion as my time allows, but I suspect it'd be better to do it in chat rather than continuing in the comments.)

@No Name - there was a rogue comma left in in the first phrase, it should have read ... Shouldn't it be "I, as a left handed person who uses the mouse with my right hand" or "I, as a left handed person, use the mouse with my right hand". In the second case The key (and complete) phrase would be "I use the mouse with the right hand", with "as a left handed person" being extra information. My point was that in the first case the subject is third person and the second it is first person.

@timchessish Why don't we get notified when our comments are upvoted? It's certainly better than this nonsense where I have to extend the conversation to make sure you know I know that I understand and accept your rebuttal. We need a fav system
